# Work with two databases Yii 1

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii

I has two databases. I want to get some values from first and save them to second, but I dont want to create model for tables in second database, if I use code like this will be ok ?

```
$user = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->select('username, password')
->from('tbl_user')
->where('id=:id', array(':id'=>1))
->queryRow();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define as many databases if you want in your app

```
'components' => array(
    'db' => array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=dbserver1;dbname=my1db',
        ...
    ),
    'otherdb' => array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=dbserver2;dbname=my1db2',
        ...
    ),
```

and then you can use this as

```
$user = Yii::app()->otherdb->createCommand()
    ->select('username, password')
    ->from('tbl_user')
    ->where('id=:id', array(':id'=>1))
    ->queryRow();
```

There is a few good articles covering most of this on the yii wiki :

- http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/123/multiple-database-support-in-yii/
- http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/544/multiple-database-connection-select-database-based-on-login-user-id-dynamic/
- http://yiihaa.com/models-and-multiple-database-connections

If you don't quiet get it, do read the comments in that article, some good stuff there.